# Restsharp. How to get the response details

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, restsharp

So, in a `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>` console app, I'm  using `RestSharp` and trying to get the error message from a `PATCH` request. This is what Postman returns:

[image: Postman response]

However, I can't figure out how to get this message in my C# code:

```
static RestResponse createOrUpdateElement(RestClient client, RestRequest request, string urlSuffix)
{
    RestResponse response = new RestResponse();
    RestResponse responsep = new RestResponse(); client.Get(request);

    client.Options.ThrowOnAnyError = true;

    try
    {
        
        response = client.Get(request);
        
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // If the call was successful, update the record's status to "Synchronized"
            var existing = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(response.Content);
            if (existing.TryGetProperty("value", out JsonElement value))
            {
                if (value.GetArrayLength() == 0)
                {
                    client = GetRestClient(urlSuffix);
                    response = client.Post(request);

                }
                //HERE I MAKE THE PATCH REQUEST 
                else
                {
                    JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(value[0]).TryGetProperty("SystemId", out JsonElement systemId);
                    request.AddHeader("If-Match", "*");
                    client = GetRestClient(urlSuffix + "(" + systemId.ToString() + ")");
                    responsep = client.Patch(request);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        responsep.ResponseStatus = ResponseStatus.Error;
        responsep.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        responsep.ErrorException = ex;
    }

    return response;
}
```

This is what I get in when debugging:

[image: C# Response]

Also tried with Execute, but I get the same Exception (BadRequest), I can't figure out how to get the 400 error I get in Postman:

```
//responsep = client.Patch(request);
request.Method = Method.Patch;           
responsep = client.Execute(request);
```

This is what I have, if I don't use try and catch:

[image: No try/catch]

Comment: Don't `ThrowOnAnyError`.

Comment: Have you tried to place a breakpoint and see whether this line `responsep = client.Patch(request);` get hit? If this line is hit and returned with value, you should be able to get the error info from `responsep`.

Comment: @CodeCaster tried with true and with false for ````ThrowOnAnyError````, same behaviour

Comment: @YongShun The line gets hit, but i goes straight to the catch block. As You can see in the screenshot, ````responsep```` is not even modified, it has the same ````StatusCode : 0```` from the constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get it from here:

```
catch (HttpException ex)
{
    if (ex.Response != null)
    {
        // Check those values
        string statusDescription = ex.Response.StatusDescription;
        string errorMessage = ex.Response.Content;
    }
}
```

or you can set `client.Options.ThrowOnAnyError = false;`
set `request.Method = Method.Post;`
and use execute instead of patch  `response = client.Execute(request);`
to read response details from response object

Comment: sorry didn't mention that my project was ````<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>````, so ````HttpException```` is not available

Comment: isn't HttpException just deprecated there? I think you should be able to use RestApiException if i remember it correctly

Comment: Havent found any class or type "RestApiException" in C#

Comment: ah right. I just reread the docs and it seems it won't work with Patch. Only Idea I have is to try with `Execute` and create Request manually instead of `Patch`. You can read the response then

Comment: Even with ````Execute```` I don't get the 400 exception. What a headache

Comment: What I ment is this: https://restsharp.dev/error-handling.html
If you set ThrowOnAnyError to false then Execute by default will not throw exception on failed request. You should be able to get details directly from response

Comment: wow @jaro ! Finally ````client.Options.ThrowOnAnyError = false; request.Method = Method.Post; response = client.Execute(request);```` This way I got the body I needed in ````response```` Please update answer so I UpVote. Thanks!